# WP from remote to local

Tags: wordpress

I really hope you can help me!

I need to make some changes on a WP website from Xampp on my mac.

I did the backup of the DB and via FTP I copied all the files in XAMPP/htdocs/b

I modified the wp-config.php as follow:

```
   define('DB_NAME', 'db:name');
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

after importing the DB I also changed the siteurl under wp_options.

Now my problem is this... wen I open the website no pictures loads and any link goes to /xampp/ folder

I tried so many things but nothing seams to work. I cannot even access the wp-login.php due to user and psw wrong.

please please help!

***** I realise that img url is:  img src="/wp-content/themes/nm/images/common/impcontent/mapfiller.jpg"   so it looks for the imgs into the localhost/wp-content/... insted of localhost/b/wp-content/... how do I change that???

Comment: You need to create a virtual host in order to run the site. Once that is done you have to do a search and replace your-site.com with your-local-site.com in the database. This will fix all the missing links and pages.

Comment: I had done the search and replace in database but still the same

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php set the following values to your proper values:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Once this is working, install and run https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ to fix the path issues.

Comment: I added the following to wp-config.php the following: define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/b');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/b'); But still not working and once I cannot login the the admin pannel I cannot install the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query in phpmyadmin, note: wp_ is prefix of table. If you have changed the prefix of the table at the time of installation then use that prefix with wp_ in the below query

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here');
```

Comment: For the above query try using the URL with and with out "HTTP". Hope this help you

Comment: I know you searched the database, but search the database with the filter as the domain name only (not with http and domain type) from where you have taken the backup

Comment: I realize that the img are not loded because the link doesent have the folder after localhost... localhost/wp-content/themes... insted of localhost/b/wp-content/themes

Comment: ok I thought you have taken backup of also the images in themes, so your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/wp-sync-db/wp-sync-db

Install it both on localhost and on remote. Follow the instructions, set correct domains and push from local to remote. It should work nice :)